# Crptic error in glslc: syntax error, unexpected FLOATCONSTANT, expecting RIGHT_PAREN

Tags: glsl

I use this complex type everywhere in a few shaders and finally, I get this error:

```
glslangValidator -S comp help.glsl
```

help.glsl:14: error: '' :  syntax error, unexpected FLOATCONSTANT, expecting RIGHT_PAREN
1 error generated.

A reproducer is here:

```
#version 460

struct cmplx {
  float re;
  float im;
};

cmplx
fresnel_cont_frac(float ax)
{
    const float pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

    const float pix2 = pi * ax * ax;
    cmplx b(1.0, -pix2);

    return b;
}
```

The blowup is the constructor for `b`. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You do not declared any constructor for the cmplx and I am not sure if you even can for a struct in GLSL. Try this instead:

```
#version 460
struct cmplx
    {
    float re;
    float im;
    };
cmplx ld(float re,float im){ cmplx c; c.re=re; c.im=im; return c; }

cmplx fresnel_cont_frac(float ax)
    {
    const float pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    const float pix2 = pi * ax * ax;
    cmplx b=ld(1.0, -pix2);
    return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use C++-style ctors in GLSL. You have to explicitly call the struct name with args and assign (or make a constructor function as @Spektre noted above):

```
#version 460

struct cmplx {
  float re;
  float im;
};

cmplx
fresnel_cont_frac(float ax)
{
    const float pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

    const float pix2 = pi * ax * ax;
    cmplx b = cmplx(1.0, -pix2);

    return b;
}
```